# Why the command to clean is not working in Gradle React native project?

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, react-native

I am trying to clean Gradle files after `cd .\android`, but it's not working. Please see the below command.

```
D:\ReactNativeVS\demo\android>./gradlew clean
```

I get the following error:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: You need to install gradle to be able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by running: `gradlew clean`, without `./`

Comment: D:\ReactNativeVS\demo\android>./gradlew cleanBuildCache
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. same issue not able to fix..

Comment: try without `./` just: `gradlew clean`

Comment: try without ./ just: gradlew clean  add this in answer section it will help developers.

Comment: guys, i can run gradlew clean in windows cmd,  Can not run in vs code.  it says as gradlew clean is not internal or external command.

Comment: @SkySakthi it might be vs code is using different terminal.